# DFS to find all possible paths - Where am I going wrong?

Tags: c, graph-traversal

I need to implement DFS to find all possible paths from a vertex, say    "item"
So far I have the following and I cannot understand where I am going wrong.

```
void dfs()
{
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=nodecount;i++)
    {
        visited[i]=0;
    }
    push(item);
    while(top!=0)
    {
        pop();
        visited[item]=1;
        for(i=1;i<nodecount;i++)
        {
            if(topo[item][i]==1)
            {
                if(visited[i]==0)
                {
                    item=i;
                    visited[i]=1;
                    push(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example:
If I have an undirected graph where

- node 1 is connected to 2,4
- node 2 is connected to 1,4,3
- node 3 is connected to 2,5,6
- node 4 is connected to 1,2,5
- node 5 is connected to 4,3,6
- node 6 is connected to 3,5

With this code, if item = 2 then I should get

- 2-1-4-5-6-3
- 2-1
- 2-1-4
- 2-2-1-5-6-3

and so on.

But I am getting

- 2
- 1
- 1-4
- 1-4-5
- 1-4
- 1-4-3
- 1

Comment: What is that you think is wrong ?

Comment: Instead of getting a path like say "1 2 4 5" if the item is "1", I am getting "2 3 2 4" or something like that. Firstly, the nodes are repeating even though I am keeping track of which nodes are visited. Secondly, the source (item) is not figuring in the list of nodes in the path.

Comment: `while(top!=0) {...}` You dont't change the value of `top`, do you? However, you will need to provide some more information. You need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am using top=0 for empty stack

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't overwrite (break) `item` when `visited[i]==0`.

Moreover, the range differs in initialization and DFS.

There are some more corrections.

```
void dfs()
{
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=nodecount;i++)
    {
        visited[i]=0;
    }
    visited[item]=1; /* add this to mark the start point as visited */
    push(item);
    while(top!=0)
    {
        pop();
        /* delete visited[item]=1; here */
        for(i=1;i<=nodecount;i++) /* changed < to <= */
        {
            if(topo[item][i]==1)
            {
                if(visited[i]==0)
                {
                    visited[i]=1; /* item is unchanged unless push change it */
                    push(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Not knowing, I believe that `push` and `pop` do proper work with `item` and `top`, and that there are enough elements in `visited`.

In case of `push` assumes that `item` will be passed as the parameter, try this instead:

```
void dfs()
{
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=nodecount;i++)
    {
        visited[i]=0;
    }
    visited[item]=1; /* add this to mark the start point as visited */
    push(item);
    while(top!=0)
    {
        pop();
        /* delete visited[item]=1; here */
        for(i=1;i<=nodecount;i++) /* changed < to <= */
        {
            if(topo[item][i]==1)
            {
                if(visited[i]==0)
                {
                    int item_bak = item;
                    item = i;
                    visited[item]=1;
                    push(item);
                    item = item_bak;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the <= correction. Missed it. If I don't change item then the same node will get pushed into the stack again and again. Isn't it?

Comment: @user24603 Sorry, `i` should be used instead of `item`. Edited.

Comment: I tried the new edit you suggested. It still won't work the way I want it. Still getting the same output as with the original code.

Answer (score 0):

What about a recursive function for that?

```
void dfs(int item) {
  int i;
  push(item);
  visited[item] = 1;
  pstack();

  for(i=1; i<nodecount; i++) {
    if ((nodes[item][i] == 1) && (visited[i] == 0)) {
      dfs(i);
      visited[i] = 0;
    }
  }
  pop();
}
```

Here pstack() is a function that prints the content of the stack, and this function must be called with visited[] inited to 0.
Using the same graphe than you I get:

```
. 2 
. 2 1 
. 2 1 4 
. 2 1 4 5 
. 2 1 4 5 3 
. 2 3 
. 2 3 5 
. 2 3 5 4 
. 2 3 5 4 1 
. 2 4 
. 2 4 1 
. 2 4 5 
. 2 4 5 3
```

I made 'item' a parameter of the function. Note: starting counts at 1 is not really C-aware :)